# SharePoint 2010: When to provision two Search Service Applications?

Tags: search, security, service-application

I am working in a single farm with two distinct web applications.  Each web application's content needs to be isolated from the other.  Should I provision two Search Service Applications or use a single Search SA and rely on security trimming, separate content source indexing, and proper scopes?

I am already planning on unique content access accounts for crawling each web application.

Comment: "Each web application's content needs to be isolated from the other."

What do you mean with "isolated"?

Comment: Basically, I want the indexed content separate and secure.  I do not want a query from site A to return results from site B, even if a poorly created scope included both content sources.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Two search service applications make sense when you need to make sure, that "a query from site A to return results from site B, even if a poorly created scope included both content sources".
You will then use search service application proxies to assign each web application their own search service application. This will give you a good level of security- however, you should be aware that security trimming might not work as aspected when users permissions change frequently and/or are extremly complex.

Comment: Thanks!  What do you mean when you say trimming might not work as expected?  Will people start seeing documents that they shouldnt?  Or not see documents they should?

Comment: Security trimming might fail if permissions change between two crawls. Example: (1) You add permissions for DOC_LIB_1 to user JIM today. (2) You remove permissions for SECRET_LIB_1 for user JANE today. (3) You run your next crawl next sunday. In this scenario JIM won't find content from DOC_LIB_1 even though he has got permission. However, JANE will still find content from SECRET_LIB_1. Even though she is not allowed to open the documents, the title, properties and the lines of text are exposed.